# angular-ui-router error - Error: invalid 'handler' in when()

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I am using angular 1.5 and angular-ui-router version 0.2.18

My app.js file looks like this:

```
import angular from 'angular';
import uiRouter from 'angular-ui-router';
import 'angular-ui-bootstrap';
import './components/logIn/logIn';
import './components/home/home';

    angular.module('app', ['ui.bootstrap', 'app.components', uiRouter])
      .controller('mainCtrl', function() {
      })
      .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$urlMatcherFactoryProvider', function($stateProvider,   $urlRouterProvider,   $urlMatcherFactoryProvider){
        $urlRouterProvider
          .when('/home', {
            template: '<home></home>'
          })
          .otherwise({
            redirectTo: '/home'
          });
      }]);
```

I get the following error:

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app
>   due to: Error: invalid 'handler' in when()
>       at $UrlRouterProvider.when (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:511:2), :1916:13)
>       at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:493:2), :20:22)
>       at Object.invoke (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :4604:19)
>       at runInvokeQueue (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :4497:35)
>       at eval (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :4506:11)
>       at forEach (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :321:20)
>       at loadModules (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :4487:5)
>       at createInjector (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :4409:19)
>       at doBootstrap (eval at  (http://localhost:8080/app.bundle.js:505:2), :1691:20)

I think it is the `template` property.  Is it not possible to set the templat like this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are confusing [`urlRouterProvider`](http://angular-ui.github.io/ui-router/site/#/api/ui.router.router.$urlRouterProvider) with [`routeProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider).

The latter is used to define the routes (and their templates among ther rest).
You use the first one to do redirects for when a URL isn't matched (either as a string or a function). The `otherwise` you used belongs to the `$routeProvider` as well.

So just switch and you should be good to go:

```
$routeProvider.when('/home', {
    template: '<home></home>'
});

// or $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');
$routeProvider.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
```

Comment: Could you please show me the full module code because with angular 1.5, I still get the error.  Does $routeProvider come from 'ui.rouiter' or 'ngRoute'?

Comment: $routerProvider is with ngRoute, are you using ui.router ? If so you need to use $stateProvider.

Comment: Yes, I stated that in the title of the question.  Sorry if that was not clear.

Comment: Oh sorry, haven't noticed. You need to change to $stateProvider and also use `.state` instead of `.when`. So `.when('/home', ...` would be `.state('home', ...` (also notice the removal of '/')